# First WiFi connection in MicroPython fails on RP2040

Tags: wifi, micropython

I'm running MicroPython on my Raspberry Pi Pico and trying to connect it to my WiFi with the following code:

```py
wifi = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wifi.active(True)
print(wifi.isconnected())
wifi.connect('<<SSID>>', '<<Password>>')
print(wifi.isconnected())
```

When running this for the very first time after plugging the Raspi into my laptop, it fails:

```py
False
False
```

When running it the next time, it succeeds for the first call of `isconnected()`:

```py
True
True
```

So I tried a loop like this:

```py
wifi = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wifi.active(True)
while not wifi.isconnected():
    print('WiFi not connected, trying to connect')
    wifi.connect('<<SSID>>', '<<Password>>')
    time.sleep(1)
```

But with this, I'm running into an infinite loop and the WiFi never succeeds. When checking my router, the Raspi seems to be properly connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a timing issue, the following code is stable and works properly:

```py
pin = Pin("LED", Pin.OUT)
pin.off()

wifi = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wifi.active(True)
time.sleep(2)
wifi.connect('<<SSID>>', '<<Password>>')
time.sleep(2)

max_wait = 10
while max_wait > 0:
    if wifi.status() < 0 or wifi.status() >= 3:
        break
    max_wait -= 1
    time.sleep(1)

if wifi.status() != 3:
    pin.on()
    raise RuntimeError('network connection failed')
else:
    pin.on()
    time.sleep(1)
    pin.off()
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you try to create a new WiFi connection again and again by calling `wifi.connect("SSID", "Password")` in the while loop.

The following example is the recommended approach taken from the [MicroPython 1.20.0 Network docs](https://docs.micropython.org/en/v1.20.0/esp8266/tutorial/network_basics.html#configuration-of-the-wifi). It once calls the `connect` function and then waits until `isconnected()` returns true. This can be of course extended with a timeout or max. retries counter

```py
def do_connect():
    import network
    sta_if = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    if not sta_if.isconnected():
        print('connecting to network...')
        sta_if.active(True)
        sta_if.connect('<ssid>', '<key>')
        while not sta_if.isconnected():
            pass
    print('network config:', sta_if.ifconfig())
```